# How to add Japanese text in Jfreechart labels for SpiderWebPlot usinf awt Font

Tags: java, fonts, itext, awt, jfreechart

I'm using Jfreechart to generate SpiderWebPlot and in my Dataset I have text in Japanese and whenever I generate this into a PDF Japaenese text doesn't appear.

```
  DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
dataset.addValue(5, "current month", "hi項目");
dataset.addValue(4, "current month", "B");
dataset.addValue(3, "current month", "C");
dataset.addValue(5, "current month", "D");
dataset.addValue(2, "current month", "E");
dataset.addValue(4, "previous month", "hi項目");
dataset.addValue(4, "previous month", "B");
dataset.addValue(2, "previous month", "C");
dataset.addValue(4, "previous month", "D");
dataset.addValue(4, "previous month", "E");
```

This is my Dataset and while setting the Font for the labels I'm doing this

```
 SpiderWebPlot spiderWebPlot = new SpiderWebPlot(dataset);

    ClassLoader classLoader = ReportVariables.class.getClassLoader();
    URL resource = classLoader.getResource("notoSansRegular.ttf");
    assert resource != null;
    var f = new File(resource.toURI());
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
    Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);

spiderWebPlot.setLabelFont(openFontTTF("notoSansRegular"));
```

I'm using Noto Sans TTF to load the Font(using java.awt.Font) . I'm still not getting what is the issue? Can someone help ?
This how my chart looks like
[image]

Comment: `Noto Sans (notoSansRegular.ttf)` does not support CJK fonts. Try `https://github.com/notofonts/noto-cjk/blob/main/Sans/Variable/TTF/NotoSansCJKjp-VF.ttf`

Answer (score 0):

No simple way to get it right whenever required, keep foreign character Strings completely separate from other String encodings, and use render GUI components for individual Strings encoded.
note: the font chosen for use should have an image of the character to render to screen but may not carry such image unless it was specifically for that language symbol *...using Noto Sans TTF to load the Font(using java.awt.Font)...*

java.awt.Font[] fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();

,..loop over the array and put the names into a String array getName(). getFamilyName()...

fontnames[] = fonts.getFontName();

but, put the text into a .properties file (special java data file and class , a java utility system) or a text file written and saved in foreign charset encoding line by line, to read from file as bytes and draw each string from.
Where you use foreign characters, put the characters into a new String with the charset name or alias encoding also in the String constructor declaration arguments.

See the api docs constructor summary for String. (note:  getbytes() method )
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

*String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)*

*String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)*

Encodings supported in Oracle Corp.  java.
note: the machine OS must have the charset installed to use the encoding specified, so check to know if it is present.    *java.nio.charset.Charset.availableCharsets()*
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

*String(StringBuilder builder)*
and also see api docs
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

insert(int offset, int i)

With StringBuilder class you can build a String by using the byte numeric value that matches each character in the charset encoding.
Or if a two byte character create a char with   (radix is usually hexadecimal)

*Character.forDigit(int digit, int radix)*

insert(int offset, char c)

Then do as above, store it into a String with charset labeled.

*Character.getName(int codePoint)*
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana_(Unicode_block)
You may need to map foreign characters to Unicode code points for UTF-8 or UTF-16 to create web pages that also respond by international ISO "locale" setting common in Java and HTML XML.

- Note when output onto panels or textareas e.t.c. the locale should be set on the GUI component to reflect the foreign characters scheme used.
  ...and after the value is placed onto or into the GUI, call repaint() with the component and also on the main component window setIgnoreRepaint(false) only once.
- There are a small number of encodings in various languages principally for "web" that carry both the language script and a limited English symbol ASCII subset together e.g. ISO-2022-JP

FINALLY choose how the locale and GUI components language script will be for use, the machine OS it is run on must have the charset.
This last point also refers to the .java source code file AND the charset flag for javac command to compile in, that being why it often is UTF-8 or UTF-16 is used against a code map of numerics for a language.

---

following link may be of some minor help with internationalization and charsets, encodings.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gjHmdC-BW0Q2vXiQYmp1rzPU497sybNy/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: ...and note, your PDF printer app setting may not be set or usable with the charset scheme...